# Jekyll - Keep a category out of the loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a category named `portfolio` and it's posts will be listed in `/portfolio/index.html`. I know how to do that but i also want to keep the posts in category `portfolio` out of the main index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some diggings and from what i've seen, this option is not yet available. But i've found a way around it:

Put all the posts that you want to list in your blog in a `blog` category except for the posts you want to list in other page or something, as in my case the posts in the `portfolio` category.

Now instead of using:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
```

to list your posts. Use:

```
{% for post in site.categories.blog %}
```

---

It's not efficient i know, but as it seems it's the only way so far.